# How to get TreeView-like file drop-down list

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I am trying to code a file drop-down list like the one in the windows file explorer but with a checkbox like shown in the picture.

I have tried using a TreeView but I couldn't find a way to get it looking right. Is there an easy way to do this or do I just have to build it from scratch with an empty canvas?
[image]

Comment: *"I couldn't find a way to get it looking right"* - We have no idea what "right" means to you, nor how it looks wrong. We also don't know which code you are using. Please see [ask].

Comment: I added a picture of what I would like it to look like.

Comment: Why don't you use a `<tkinter.Listbox>` with frames inside it. The frames will need 5 things: the correct indentation, a arrow pointing right/down, a checkbox, a picture, and the name of the folder/file. The indentation can be achieved by creating an empty frame with a set width.

Comment: There's nothing special about that image. Which part of it are you failing to implement? Which code are you exercising? Please show a [mcve].